# How to get an image url from media library

Tags: media, library

I have got an attachment id, but I need an url. How can I get an url from the attachment object?

```
// When an image is selected, run a callback.
frame.on( 'select', function() {
    // Grab the selected attachment.
    var attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first();
    $('#' + id).val(attachment.id);
});
```

...

toJSON() function convert it. Now it works.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var frame;

// Build the choose from library frame.
$(document).on("click", ".upload_image_button", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('_b', '');  

    if ( frame ) {
        frame.open();
        return;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
        // Tell the modal to show only images.
        library: {
            type: 'image'
        },
    });

    // When an image is selected, run a callback.
    frame.on( 'select', function() {
        // Grab the selected attachment.
        attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('#' + id).val(attachment.url);
    });

    frame.open();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you got an answer - please add it as such and not as edit to your question. This is encouraged by the system and will be rewarded. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert attachment variable to JSON object using toJSON() . Then you can its property.

use

```
attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
```

instead of

```
attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have attachment id then you can call `wp_get_attachment_url` function to get URL of attachment.

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); ?>
```

[`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) function accept ID.

**Example usage**... for attachment id 12.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( 12 ); ?>
```

It will output something like `http://example.net/wp-content/uploads/filename`